# namespace name soapcontext could not be found

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-c#-express-2010

I am building a form application that makes a call to a third party web service, but keep getting a `"namespace name soapcontext could not be found"` error.

I already added a web reference that points to the wsdl for the web service.  Here is what I have:

```
private void btnGetInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     QTWebSvcsService svc = new qtref.QTWebSvcsService();
     // The getVehicleInformation method accepts an AssetIdentifier and returns a
     // VehicleInfo object.  Instantiate them both.
     qtref.AssetIdentifier ai = new qtref.AssetIdentifier();
     qtref.VehicleInfo vi = new qtref.VehicleInfo();

     // Replace these strings with valid company name, user name and password
     string sUsername = "[usernasme]";
     string sCompanyname = "[company]";
     string sIdentity = sUsername + "@" + sCompanyname;
     string sPassword = "[password]";

     //This is where it fails
     SoapContext requestContext = RequestSoapContext.Current;
}
```

Here is the exact error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'SoapContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\Sophia Carter\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DemoGetVehInf\DemoGetVehInf\Form1.cs   45  13  DemoGetVehInf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you need a using statement to include the namespace that contains SoapContext.
I don't know what namespace this would be but at the top of your code you will place something like:

```
using SoapContextNamespace;
```

I personally use Visual Studio with ReSharper.  This combination of tools detects this error and offers a way to correct it with selecting something from the context menu when you right click.  Depending on your tool set, you may find this or a similar option.